# Export of a variable from a bash script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I've got to some variables which will be done with kubenetes command so I thought it best to put these in a bash script. I've managed to do that and called on it and see that variables get created but when it comes out of the bash script they are not assigned.

Within the Jenkinsfile script I have

```
steps {
    sh '''
      ./bin/kube.sh
      echo "Kube2 = ${SCRET}"
```

.....

and within the kube.sh file I have

```
#!/bin/bash

export SCRET=`kubectl -n keycloak get secret auser -o yaml | grep password | awk '{print $2}'`
echo "Kube2 = ${SCRET}"
```

I get the following results

```
+ ./bin/kube.sh
Kube1 = XXXXXXXX
+ echo 'SCRET = XXXXXXXX'
Kube2 =
```

Why is it that it gets unset again? What am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables set in a subshell evaporate with that shell, and are not exported to the parent.

To set variables in the current environment using a script, you must *source* the code into the current context.

```
$: cat x
foo=bar
$: ./x && echo $foo # runs in a subshell - foo ends with ./x

$: . x && echo $foo # runs in current shell - foo is set
bar
```

Comment: c.f. https://linuxize.com/post/bash-source-command/ for explanations and examples.